# Why does SSRS change cell width / height to > 2 decimals?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a report in SSRS which has to export nicely to Excel without merged / hidden columns and rows. To do that I've learned I have to for instance align my subreport width and height with my cell width and height and don't use width and height with more than 2 decimals (e.g. 0,55398cm).

But SSRS in some cases won't let me? When I enter a width (cell level) of 4,5cm; 0,55cm it keeps changing it to 4,5cm; 0,55001cm?

Not sure if this will influence my row / column behaviour in Excel..

Regards,

Mike

Comment: Personally I rarely go to 2 decimal places when aligning data with headers. One is normally enough! Try reducing your dimensions and see if that helps!